# Reaching subsites of SharePoint domain

Tags: rest, api

I am writing an application that scrapes all the files from a given SharePoint site and all of its sub-sites.

This worked perfectly when I ran it locally however, now that it's running on a server there were some changes that had to be made.

Previously I could just reach the site from the program through it's name `[SharepointSiteName]`

Now however I need to address it through the domain `[SharepointSiteName].example.com`.

This works when I'm asking for the files of the root site but once I get to the sub-sites it doesn't find the files any more.

All of the scraping makes use of the SharePoint API, so as an example:

```
[sharepointsitename]/[subsite]/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('[sharepointsitename]/[subsite]/Shared%20Documents')/files 
**Works**

[sharepointsitename].example.com/[subsite]/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('[sharepointsitename]/[subsite]/Shared%20Documents')/files 
**Doesn't Work**
```

The program is written in Java and switching to C# is not an option.

Is there a way around this? I could be missing something obvious here since I am fearly new to SharePoint and didn't really know how to look for the answer as well.

Comment: Check this out: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3s_uY983LXM & http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepoint_strategery/archive/2013/05/27/alternate-access-mappings-explained.aspx